# uwp softwarebitmap insufficient memory calling copyfromBuffer()

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing an UWP application which has to receive a video stream from a remote pc.
Right now I'm capturing the video from the PC's webcam, sending it to a remote server which return it to me over a TCP socket.
I've been able to succesfully do this thing with an audio stream.

The problem occours when I receive a portion of the video stream as a byte array and try to create a SoftwareBitmap whach has to be represented in a XAML Image element.

The source code is structured to fire an event when a videoframe has been captured, then convert it to a byte[], write it on the TCP socket; when a message is received on the socket another event is fired in order to feed the UI with a single image.

Here the portion of the code in which i get the Exception:

```
 var reader = (DataReader)sender;    
 try
 {
      SoftwareBitmap img = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 1280, 720);                  
      img.CopyFromBuffer(reader.ReadBuffer(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
      ImageReadyEvent(SoftwareBitmap.Convert(img, 
                                             BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 
                                             BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore), null);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {    
      throw;
 }
```

The exception is fired when **img.CopyFromBuffer(reader.ReadBuffer(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));** is called.

At that moment the value of **reader.UnconsumedBufferLength** is 55000 byte.

The same code works perfectly if I execute it right after the video frame is ready, without sending it over the socket.

I've also tryed a BitmapDecoder but it fails everytime, with both the possible overrides of `BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync();`

I'm not figuring out how to solve this issue, anyone has an advice to make this thing work?

Comment: You forgot the `using` statement, required to prevent the amount of unmanaged memory used by SoftwareBitmap from exploding.  If you still have trouble then switch the Platform Target to x64.

Comment: Even with the **using** statement the exception is thrown, this instruction, even if I run that instruction only one time. I'm already building the project for x64.

Comment: Consider that the underlying cause is another one, UWP exceptions don't win any prizes.  You for example do nothing obvious to ensure that *all* the bytes needed to construct the image are properly copied.  If you do this over TCP then you always need a protocol.  A very simple one is first writing the number of bytes, then the image bytes.

Comment: Have you compared the received data with the source data? Does it match?

Comment: I've solved this issue, the problem was caused by a mismatch in the buffer size allocation, the client was receiving chunks of data which size didn't match with frame's one.

Comment: Of course @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: @Marco Thanks for this comment. I had same issue. Didn't cross my mind that insuficience memory is memory of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct,  It may mismatch in the buffer when transfer over TCP socket. Please try to compare the received data with the source data. And optimize  your transport protocol.